# Inserting PRIMARY Key value into SQL without duplicating the CHAR via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Once again needed help from you experts, 
Heres the design

SQL
MemberID CHAR(8)

The memberID usually is "M1" "M2" and so on
However when I add into SQL via ASP.NET
The command would be something like

List memList = member.GetAllMem(); // Basically retrieve from SQL and store inside a list

AddMember("M" + Convert.ToString(memberList.count() +1);

The problem with above code is when I delete member value inside SQL the numbering of the member would have problem and can be duplicate when I insert new member (because I use the Count) 
How to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case the logic would be to get the last row from the table, get primary key value of that row, get the number value from it ("splitting M and number), increment it by one  and use it to create new primary key value.

Comment: Don't try to roll your own auto-increment column. It's bound to fail. Instead, use the built in auto-increment mechanism of the database you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to maintain the auto-increment by yourself but if you insist you could create a sequence and select a new value from it every time you need to insert into the table.

Create sequence like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Counter1
  START WITH 1  
  INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

And every time you need a new value select the next value from it as:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Counter1;
```

For more information please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql